# What is the difference between sub Foo::bar {} and sub bar {} when they both belong to package Foo?

Tags: perl

Assume we have code like this

```
package Foo;
sub bar {
    say 'hi';
}
```

and this

```
package Foo;
sub Foo::bar {
    say 'hi';
}
```

I thought they are equivalent, so we can do this

```
Foo->bar();
```

whether we define the method with fully qualified name or not. However, in some circumstances they are indeed different. For instance, in the example given by `perldoc -f require`, the method `INC` must be fully qualified with the package name:

```
# In Foo.pm
package Foo;
sub new { ... }
sub Foo::INC {
    my ($self, $filename) = @_;
    ...
}
# In the main program
push @INC, Foo->new(...);
```

If we don't fully qualify the method name, then a compile-time error occurs. So, what is the difference between full qualified name and no package name prepended?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mechanism that causes `@main::INC` to be globally accessible as `@INC` also causes `sub INC { }` to mean `sub main::INC { }`.

Quote [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html),

> Perl identifiers that begin with digits, control characters, or punctuation characters are exempt from the effects of the `package` declaration and are always forced to be in package `main`; they are also exempt from `strict 'vars'` errors. A few other names are also exempt in these ways:
>
> ```
> ENV STDIN
> INC STDOUT
> ARGV STDERR
> ARGVOUT
> SIG
> ```

---

> *If we don't fully qualify the method name, then a compile-time error occurs.*

hum... It won't do what you want, but it won't cause a compile-time error either.

```
$ perl -ce'
    package Foo;
    sub new { ... }
    sub INC {
        my ($self, $filename) = @_;
        ...
    }

    push @INC, Foo->new("...");
'
-e syntax OK
```

Comment: The compile-time error I encountered probably came from the failure of loading the modules needed.

Answer (score 2):

`perldoc -f require` states why this is so:

> If the hook is an object, it must provide an INC method that will be called as above, the first parameter being the object itself. (Note that you must fully qualify the sub’s name, as unqualified "INC" is always forced into package "main".)

It would thus be as if you wrote `sub main::INC {}` if you leave the package qualifier out. I can't tell you why this is happening, but my guess is this is one of the special cases in the interpreter.

Comment: Pardon my edit. I was going to add to your answer, but I retracted it because the passage you quoted has nothing to do with the reason `sub Foo::INC` needs to be qualified.